# Keep BOOL instead of bool

Tags: c++, boolean

I know, that `bool` is used in C++, while `BOOL` is a Microsoft specific type that is defined as an `int`.

My code is using `BOOL` as it was made for Windows to start with, but I'm trying to keep things the same way without changing my code from `BOOL` to bool, when I'm going port it to Mac.

Could something like this work?

```
    typedef int8_t _Bool;         
    typedef _Bool (BOOL);
    static const BOOL False = 0;
    static const BOOL True = 1;
```

If yes, is there a better way and why? 
If not, then why and what should I do instead?

Comment: Writing multi-language source files is hard! I suggest you stick to 1 language at a time.

Comment: I should, but i'm trying to port stuff from A to B without much changes to the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `BOOL` is defined as an `int`, you don't know without checking whether some of the code you're porting somehow *relies* on it being an `int`.

Therefore, I would go for something like:

```
#if NOT_MICROSOFT
    typedef int BOOL;
    #define TRUE 1
    #define FALSE 0
#endif
```

If you have the opportunity to check that the code you're porting will work correctly regardless of whether the type `BOOL` is really `int` or really `bool`, then most likely you have the opportunity to change it to use `bool` (or to use `int8_t`, whatever you prefer).

Answer (score 7):

I don't see why a good IDE couldn't make a global change from BOOL to bool.  I'd prefer having greater portability.  I wouldn't like the typedefs, because it'd be harder to read.

Comment: True, just wanted to keep the code the same or almost the same without much changes

Comment: It's your opportunity to make a beneficial change - take advantage.  A band-aid now won't ever come off.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem that I see with rolling your own `bool` is that template specifications that recognize `bool` will not recognize `BOOL`, going the default route. Specifically, `vector<bool>` uses a different code base to save space by packing bits in a representation of the vector; using `vector<BOOL>` will result in a representation that is roughly eight times larger.

Comment: So what the best way of porting it?

Comment: @user1417815 I would use `typedef BOOL bool` on platforms where `bool` is available, and adding `static const BOOL False = false` and `static const BOOL True = true` for compatibility with code that uses BOOL/True/False.

Comment: Memory/speed is not the main priority nowadays, but readability is. Don't confuse readers with types that aren't useful. Also, most bugs are in Your code and not the compiler. For you it's not important if the compiler uses a vector<bool>, unless you send binary data to another computer e.g. an IP frame. Microsoft makes it worse, if you put their OK in a boolean then it is false without compiler warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in topmost header file:

```
#ifndef /* MICROSOFT specific macro */
typedef bool BOOL;
static const BOOL True  = true;  // True  or TRUE
static const BOOL False = false; // False or FALSE
#endif
```

The other options can be using compile time option for pre-defining macro, e.g. `g++ -DBOOL=bool`

Comment: By : /* MICROSOFT specific macro */ do you mean: #ifdef _WIN32 ?

Comment: @user1417815, it may be `_WIN32` or whatever macro which would be defined for MS platform but not for other platforms like Linux, Mac and so on.